# Why do i keep getting undefined local variable or method "" for #<Context:0xf4b640> when i try to access the variable?

Tags: ruby

Even in this simple program, i just keep getting the same thing:

```
var = "string"

def ex()
  puts var
end

ex()
```

And it gives me: undefined local variable or method `var' for #Context:0xf4b640.

What is happening here???

Comment: As regards your first question, if you keep getting the same error when running the same code, you just need to be patient. It will probably work eventually. Yes, that makes no sense, but it is something we all have done at one time or another! As to your other question, "what's the problem?", it has to do with variable *scope*. [This article](https://www.cloudbees.com/blog/a-deep-dive-into-ruby-scopes)  (as well as @BroiSate's answer) speaks to that.

Comment: When defining or executing a method that has no arguments empty parentheses are unnecessary and customarily are not included. Back to "scope", use of the keyword [defined?](https://www.rubyguides.com/2018/10/defined-keyword/) can sometimes provide insight.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Well i am comfortable using parantheses in methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

External local variables are not accessible within methods defined with `def` keyword (as `def` creates brand new context, completely separated from its surrounding context). You can access it however in methods defined with `define_method`:

```
var = "string"

define_method :ex do
  puts var
end

ex
```

Note however, that you should rarely need this (and it can turn your coding life into hell). Just use objects and instance_variables instead.